# Django cannot import models

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following in `xsd_messages/forms.py`

```
import xsd_training.models

class UpdateRequestForm(forms.Form):
    lesson = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=xsd_training.models.Lesson.objects.all())
```

This gives the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/will/env/xSACdb/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/will/env/xSACdb/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/will/env/xSACdb/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/will/env/xSACdb/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/home/will/env/xSACdb/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/will/local/xSACdb/xsd_members/models.py", line 6, in <module>
    from xsd_training.models import PerformedLesson
  File "/home/will/local/xSACdb/xsd_training/models.py", line 8, in <module>
    import xsd_messages.views
  File "/home/will/local/xSACdb/xsd_messages/views.py", line 15, in <module>
    from xsd_messages.forms import MailingComposeForm, UpdateRequestForm
  File "/home/will/local/xSACdb/xsd_messages/forms.py", line 14, in <module>
    class UpdateRequestForm(forms.Form):
  File "/home/will/local/xSACdb/xsd_messages/forms.py", line 26, in UpdateRequestForm
    queryset=xsd_training.models.Lesson.objects.all())
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'models'
```

However models does exist as proven using the shell:

```
>>> import xsd_training.models
>>> xsd_training.models.Lesson.objects.all()
[<Lesson...
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got a circular reference: members.models imports training.models, which imports messages.views, which imports mesages.forms, which imports training.models... that circularity can't be resolved, so Python reports an error.

You need to break that chain. Without seeing the code I can't help you more, but it is deeply suspicious that a models file imports a views file: that really shouldn't happen.

Comment: Not something I've done before, starting to realise it's a really bad idea! I have some static methods inside the view that are wanted. I'm going to move these to their own module I think.

Answer (score 0):

Moved `import xsd_messages.views` in `xsd_training.models` to inside a function rather than at the top of the file.

Comment: yes, but still had the design flaw of importing a views file in a models file, most likely would have broken when tested. See Daniel Roseman's answer